# postgresql, convert unsigned number (from mysql) to signed (e.g 65535 to -32768 for smallint)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm migrating a MySQL database to postgresql and I'm facing a trivial problem

the database is storing a column `hash_something` which is a `unsigned integer` on MySQL, this hash is a 32 bit murmur hash v3

The problem is that now I can't find a way on how to convert these numbers to signed version.

Of course a workaround would be to use a bigint, so that it fits, but it would takes much more place and slow down queries (as we have hundred of millions of row)

So is there a way in either MySQL or Postgresql to do the conversion , as I care only about the fact it's an "optimized types for storing 32 bits" ?

Comment: What happens when you don't convert?

Comment: @wvdz  PostgreSQL is complaining that the value is out of range (I've exported the data as a CSV from MySQL , and reimporting it PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished by creating this function in MySQL side

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_unsigned_to_signed_preserving_bits_32(
  x  BIGINT UNSIGNED
)
RETURNS BIGINT SIGNED
DETERMINISTIC 
RETURN
  CASE
      WHEN x < POW(2,31) THEN x
      ELSE x - POW(2,32)
  END
;
```

so now I can do

```
mysql> select convert_unsigned_to_signed_preserving_bits_32(4294967295) as signed  ;
+--------+
| signed |
+--------+
|     -1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @muistooshort for char(8)  no, because the hash needs to be fast, hence why murmur, and so I don't want to convert them back and for to hexa string, for bit(n) or bytea, I havent check, the C function I use returns me a int32 so I was finding it convenient. My use case is that I use these hash in indexes  to do `where` on them and I have 4 columns like that with a composite index, so I'm naively (without any sarcasm) thinking it may maters to be int instead of bigint ?

Comment: Isn't your application going to need to be modified to do a similar manipulation?  Whenever an unsigned 32-bit value is compared to the values stored in the column? So, instead of `WHERE signed_col = 4294967295`, it would need to be changed to do a `WHERE signed_col = -1` ?

Comment: @spencer7593 , yes but my code was going to be modified anyway as I'm moving from mysql to postgresql, so using a int32 instead of uint32 is really a small change compare to the database switch :)

Comment: If you don't mind doing some work in C, it wouldn't be difficult to create an unsigned int data type.

Another option is to start with the field being bigint and then do something like ALTER TABLE ... TYPE int USING (column - 2^31).

Comment: @JimNasby , unfortunately I'm using amazon RDS and I can't manipulate the postgresql as I wish :( , I'm going to try your alter table version